# Visual Basic 6. Global/Public Folder Location That Limited User Can Write Data

Tags: vb6

I am a vb6 coder, and facing problem with a Windows 7 UAC issue.

Limited User:
When I run my installer, it asks for an admin account password, I enter and it installed it correctly.
My app writes dates to a common application data folder so that all users can access the file/data.

In Windows 7, the path is :

```
C:\ProgramData\<CompanyName>\<AppName/Title>\Config.ini
```

as my installer runs with admin rights, it creates those subfolders correctly.

But, when the app runs from a limited user account. It failed to write at that location (it actually writes to virtual path).

But, I want to write to that exact file.

However, I have researched enough and every where it is told to write in `CommonAppData` folder. 
But it still fails.

please some one help me out.

I use `SHGetSpecialFolderLocation` API call to get the folder location and I use folder id 35.

below is the sample code for the path:

```
strAPPPath = fGetSpecialfolder(35) & "\" & App.CompanyName & "\" & Trim(App.Title)
```

Comment: I have used an installer post install custom action to run a bat file to change the folders security, there is probably a better way of doing it but that worked for me.

Comment: How does it fail? Wrong path? Permissions? Subdirectory created by installer with admin rights and therefore not writeable by regular users?

Comment: @MSalters As I read the question it doesn't fail, the uac grabs it and writes to a virtual path. When I ran into the issue it was because of folder permissions.

Comment: @MarkHall.. sir, yes you are write it is UAC Virtualization issue. However can you give me the bat file that you use to set the folder permission. and also i think i need to run that bat file only one windows vista and 7 right?

Comment: Not by PC now will post info later.

Comment: What are you using for an installer.

Comment: @MarkHall, sir, is installer related with this issue ( i don't think so) however i use "Astrum InstallWizard". And how long it would take to give me that bat file? would you please give it to me :) thanks again for your kind replies.. :)

Comment: @user1544570 Just posted an answer, I didn't post the entire file just the line that sets the permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't trying to suggest that your installer was the problem, I wanted to know what capabilities that your installer had. As I said I am running a post install Custom Action, in it I make my directory, set the permissions on it and copy my config files to it. It looks like your Installer has the ability to do *Interactive and Shell Operations*, but since I am not familiar with it I will refrain trying to give you an example. The command that I use to set the permissions of the Directory is the dos [`calcs`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cacls.mspx?mfr=true) command. And the command line that I use is.

```
cacls "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\**<Your Directorys here>**" /E /P BUILTIN\Users:F
```

I was hoping someone would jump in and give an alternative way to do this, since I would like to loose the bat file.

Comment: sir, when i enter this %ALLUSERSPROFILE% this on my xp address bar. it returns this path:

C:\Documents and Settings\All Users

instead of :
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data

But on win7

C:\ProgramData

any idea sir?

and also i think i don't need worry about xp as that bat/script only need to run on vista/7 right?

thanks again for your kind help

best regards

Comment: The directories are equivalent, but you are right you only need to do it on Vista/7/8, though if you do not have permissions on Xp it probably will give you an error.

Comment: dear sir, i have tried it but didn't works..
my setting file path is: (example on windows 7)

C:\ProgramData\My Company Name\My App Name\Config.ini

so, i use this in bat file:
cacls "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\My Company Name" /E /P BUILTIN\Users:F

then i check that folder security and it shows that ("USERS") have full access. But still windows redirect writes to that settings file to virtual path :(

any idea please?

do i need to apply permission/security to all sub folders and the file it-self too? or?

please sir, help me...

thanks in advance

best regards

Comment: You need to probably do your `My AppName` directory also, I only had one level of directory, no company name just appname. I just saw your edit apply it to all sub folders, you shouldn't have to do it to the file. Also be aware that I am running this through my installer so it has elevated permissions, if you are running from a command line make sure you run cmd with admin rights.

Comment: yes sir, that bat is excueted by installer (with admin rights) lets try with both folder. and will update you in sec.. 

thanks a lot for you awesome and fast responses.. 

i am so pleased

best regards

Comment: sir, i am sorry to say but either you are wrong.. or may be something strange happens :(
i tried with both folder.. but that didn't work. 

and now i just set permission to the settings file directly and it works :)

any idea? however thanks again for your help

best regards

Comment: You should set the permissions to the folder before you copy the file to it. The file will inherit the settings of the folder. As I said earlier I figure there probably is a better way to do this, but this is all I could come up with when windows 7 was released. In my bat file I create the directorys, set permissions to the directory then copy the files to the directory. See if that resolves it for you

Comment: yes that could be the cause, because my installer first copy that file to that folder and then later run the bat file. Is that the issue?

Comment: however sir, i have found code (for vb6) to set the folder/file security.So, no need to run the bat file you can do it programatically. So, if you are a vb6 coder ( i assume/think) then i can provide/share the code with you if you want.. 

again thanks for your kind help

best regards

Comment: My guess is that probably is it, if you can set the permission on the file and it works. I already had permissions set when I copied the file and I didn't have to set it on the file itself.

Comment: I am in the process of migrating my VB6 applications to .Net, but put what you found in an answer to your question, that way anyone else with the same problem can reference it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using procmon from www.sysinternals.com (which redirects to MS Technet) and find the disk access that your application is making to access the data folder.

It will give you a better error message that should point you in the right direction, such as permissions.